# How to use "sed" shell command to obfuscate info indicated by certain character

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to write a shell command "sed" or "grep" to obfuscate information followed by "Scraped from" with a single "*".

For example, the sample file has:

```
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/> (referer: None)
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”', 'tags': ['change', 'deep-thoughts', 'thinking', 'world'], 'author': 'Albert Einstein'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'text': '“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”', 'tags': ['abilities', 'choices'], 'author': 'J.K. Rowling'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'text': '“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”', 'tags': ['inspirational', 'life', 'live', 'miracle', 'miracles'], 'author': 'Albert Einstein'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'text': '“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.”', 'tags': ['aliteracy', 'books', 'classic', 'humor'], 'author': 'Jane Austen'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'text': "“Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.”", 'tags': ['be-yourself', 'inspirational'], 'author': 'Marilyn Monroe'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'text': '“Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.”', 'tags': ['adulthood', 'success', 'value'], 'author': 'Albert Einstein'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
```

The output should have:

```
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/> (referer: None)
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from *
{'text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”', 'tags': ['change', 'deep-thoughts', 'thinking', 'world'], 'author': 'Albert Einstein'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from *
{'text': '“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”', 'tags': ['abilities', 'choices'], 'author': 'J.K. Rowling'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from *
{'text': '“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”', 'tags': ['inspirational', 'life', 'live', 'miracle', 'miracles'], 'author': 'Albert Einstein'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from *
{'text': '“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.”', 'tags': ['aliteracy', 'books', 'classic', 'humor'], 'author': 'Jane Austen'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from *
{'text': "“Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.”", 'tags': ['be-yourself', 'inspirational'], 'author': 'Marilyn Monroe'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from *
{'text': '“Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.”', 'tags': ['adulthood', 'success', 'value'], 'author': 'Albert Einstein'}
2016-12-09 18:57:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from *
```

I know that you can use sed 's/bla/BLA/g' to do replacement, but in my case I need to replace the information followed by certain character.And I'm not sure how should I do it.

Comment: So - the string to be replaced is always in the form `< ... />` and immediately follows the word `from` and a single space? Is `from` always in lower case, and always followed by exactly one space (never zero spaces, or two spaces, or a tab, etc.)?

Comment: Not always in '<.../>' form. It is always followed by 'from' but sometimes ':' or '='. Not exactly one space. Since these the URL is formatted by different people. So they all have their very own format. But one thing I am sure is that it is followed by 'Scraped from'

Comment: Then what needs to be replaced by * - everything that follows `from` (except perhaps a colon or equal sign, and a space)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Replace everything followed by `from` is the idea. Just very few cast there will be another `and from` followed. So like: `DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/> and from <blabalbla>` . Ideally, I would like to have the output be like: `DEBUG: Scraped from * and from *` but if that is too hard. I can live with replace everything that follows `from` with a *. (FYI the format of the second `and from` always has a space + `and` + `from` + `:/=/space`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that will keep the punctuation mark (or lack thereof) after the keyword `from`. Also assuming you only want this change after the keyphrase `Scraped from` rather than "any" `from`.

```
sed -E 's/(Scraped from[:=]?).*/\1 */g' sample_file
```

Dealing with two `from` clauses in the same line is a bit more complicated. Here's one way to do it.

Sample file (simplified):

```
cat sample_file

2016-12-09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2016-12-09 [scrapy.logstats] INFO: Scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-12-09 [scrapy.ext.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-12-09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.com/> (ref: None)
2016-12-09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from= <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
2016-12-09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
2016-12-09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from: <200 http://first/> and from: me.org
2016-12-09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <3 http://toscrape.com/>
```

Solution and output:

```
sed -E 's/(Scraped from[:=]?) .*and from/\1 * and from/;
        s/(Scraped( from[:=]? \* and)? from[:=]?).*$/\1 */' sample_file

2016-12-09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2016-12-09 [scrapy.logstats] INFO: Scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-12-09 [scrapy.ext.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-12-09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.com/> (ref: None)
2016-12-09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from= *
2016-12-09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from *
2016-12-09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from: * and from: *
2016-12-09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from *
```

Comment: @ImTrying - I just edited the reply to show one way to deal with two occurrences of "from" after "Scraped" on the same line.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tried it out on the whole file and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

> to obfuscate information followed by "Scraped from" with a single "*".

So just replace everything followed by "Screped from" by a single *:

```
sed 's/Scraped from .*/Scraped from */'
```

Comment: Hi Kamil, thank you for helping me out. This looks good. I am thinking to add `/g` for global and `/l` for ignoring cases on top of your answer. So it will be like `sed 's/Scraped from .*/Scraped from */g/l'` right? Also, in some case there will be another and from followed.

Comment: So like: `DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/> and from <blabalbla> `. Ideally, I would like to have the output be like: `DEBUG: Scraped from * and from * ` but if that is too hard. I can live with replace everything that follows from with a *. (FYI the format of the second and from always has a space + and + from + :/=/space). So in this case how should I modify the `sed` command?

Comment: @ImTrying - How does this work for the rows where the word `from` is immediately followed by a colon, as you described under your original question? KamilCuk didn't have that additional information when you posted your question; but you do, yet you say this is helping you out.

Comment: @mathguy When I was responding to KamilCuk I did not see your respond. Your solution is so far the best. I tried to give you an up vote but my reputatio is too low, so Stack Overflow did not count my vote. I am not sure why Kamil's post has an up vote. I am sorry.

Comment: @ImTrying - (1) When Kamil posted his answer, you had not provided the additional information, so his answer was correct with the info available at that time. The upvote is well deserved. (2) Don't worry about voting on my answer; I don't care about that, actually I think the whole "reputation game" is a bad joke. No worries. ... and in fact, re-reading your additional info, I see you may have to replace more than one `from` info with \*. That makes the problem more interesting; if I can solve it, I will edit my answer to address that too.

Comment: @mathguy Thank you so much for understanding and help. Apparently Stack Overflow really want to make sure the quality of the answer by only allow trust worthy people to vote lol.

Comment: Flags are just characters, it's `sed 's/Scraped from .*/Scraped from */gl'`. Well, decide what  you want to have. You want to replace the next "word" after `from` then only `<200` should be replaced, and `http://quotes.toscrape.com/>` shouldn't be resulting in `Scraped from * http://quotes.toscrape.com/> and from *`. The solution comes from you defining what you want - after that is just smart googling. You can remove everything after `from <` up until `>`.